# PhysX Skin Width

Tags: character-controller, physx

How a character controller's skin width is implemented?

I have a custom server with a traditional heightmap for terrains but when it comes to regions sitting on the terrain, I rely on 3D voxels that say whether a location is passable or not.  The problem I'm having is that my makeshift character controller is getting stuck on everything within these regions instead of sliding along them as a client's character controller would (be it Unity or Unreal Engine).  I have no idea how skin width is supposed to work but I'm intrigued by it.  My C++ code takes a hard-stop approach when it encounters an impassable voxel.  I would like to know more about how PhysX skin works.

Comment: [The PhysX documentation describes this here](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/physx/guide/Manual/CharacterControllers.html) and it looks like the [source code is available here](https://github.com/NVIDIAGameWorks/PhysX/tree/93c6dd21b545605185f2febc8eeacebe49a99479/physx/source/physxcharacterkinematic/src).

Comment: But I think this might be an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). It sounds like what you really want is "How do I implement a collide-and-slide behaviour between a capsule and voxels, without getting snagged on corners?" You think skin width could be a solution to that, but it might not be. Ask about your goal / the problem to solve, not about the stepping stone you're guessing might get you there.

Comment: I know one thing for sure, my "capsule" is really a point.  On the server side (which is what I'm talking about), I've implemented everything myself and there is no capsule or circle for my character's "collider".  I will look at the source you just pointed me to.

Comment: You probably want to model the character as having some radius if you want them to climb up over small ridges without a hard stop.

Comment: You're right.  I shouldn't be focused on skin width.  My end-goal is to be able to move smoothly throughout the level geometry without the use of any game engine and given only a 3D bitmap of what is passable/impassable. But I'm not even going to concern myself with the 3rd dimension at this point.  So, instead of a capsule collider for my character, consider a circle collider.  I want to be able to move smoothly throughout a 2D environment given a bitmap of valid positions.  I could easily adapt any solution to work in 3 dimensions for when my character is jumping or flying.

Comment: How does the radius help with that?  I guess I don't quite understand the concept.  To me it just seems like my hard stop is going to come (radius length) sooner than if I use a point like I am now.

Comment: It's easier to roll a beach ball up a flight of stairs than to roll a marble up the same. It will tend to collide with the corners of the stairs, where the collision normal has an upward component to lift it up, rather than colliding with the flat risers where the normal pushes it back only.

Comment: Right.  On a high level, the beach ball example completely makes sense.  I just don't know how to do that programmatically.  Am I checking multiple points at once instead of just one like I am now?  As the character moves, his circle might just encounter 1 point at first.  I don't know what action to take when that happens.  Let it penetrate further and there will be more intersecting points.  I still don't know which way to roll (or if I'm even on the right track here).  Also sounds very CPU intensive.

Comment: It sounds to me like you should update your question to ask "How to collide a circle against a pixel grid without getting snagged" and include a sample of the code you're using now. That can tell us a lot about how you're conceiving of the problem and what needs to change.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that.  I can't post the code as it is now because it would be too confusing.  I don't actually store a 3D bitmap (voxels) of a 3D volume.  I came up with a clever technique that stores only vertical runs of solid (1) or empty (0) for every 0.1 x 0.1 meter XZ in the volume.  I'll simplify it to 2D bitmap (pixel grid) code and post it (asking the question as you phrased it).

Comment: When someone says to update your question, please click the **Edit** link to edit your question in-place, rather than posting a new one.

Comment: Maybe I still (also) want to know how interactions work with colliders that are within the controller's skin....